# No provider for CompilerFactory after upgrade to Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular8, ivy, angular9, angular-upgrade

After I upgrade from 8 to 9, I am getting this error

`Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory]:`

`NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!`

below are the code for my main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Did you try to reinstall dependencies and running `ngcc` manually?

Comment: yes, after I update to angular 9, I did run  npm install

Answer (score 0):

Angular v9 with Ivy isn't have ngFactory files anymore
Try this:

```
platformBrowser()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Or try to bootstrap **ModuleNgFactory**.

Comment: How is your code different from the OP's code in the question?

Comment: I tried use platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule), it's still not working for me. I am still getting NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory! error